# I get empty array from promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to use promises, but I get an empty array `out`:

```
    var getProjectTestCases = function (testproject_ids){
      out = [];
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        testproject_ids.forEach(testproject_id => {
          testlink.getProjectTestCases({testprojectid: testproject_id.id}, testcases => {
            if(!Array.isArray(testcases)){
              if(testcases.string)
                out.push({id: parseInt(testcases.string)});
            }else{
              for(testcase of testcases){
                out.push({id: parseInt(testcase.string)});
              }
            }
          });
        });
//return Promise.all(out) or resolve(out)
        return Promise.all(out);
      });
    };

//empty array
getProjectTestCases([{id: 1},{id: 49}]).then(a => console.log(a));
```

That is my second solution, cause first I wrote`resolve(out)` instead of `return Promise.all(out)`

Comment: you aren't resolving the inner promise.

Comment: Before this, i called `resolve(out)` but nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Promise.all takes an array of promises as input.**

With that in mind we can rewrote your function:

```js
var getProjectTestCases = function(testproject_ids) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  
    const promises = testproject_ids.map(testproject_id => {
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        testlink.getProjectTestCases({
          testprojectid: testproject_id.id
        }, testcases => {
          if (!Array.isArray(testcases)) {
            if (testcases.string) {
              return res([{
                id: parseInt(testcases.string)
              }])
            } else {
              return res(false)
            }
          } else {
            let out = []
            for (testcase of testcases) {
              out.push({
                id: parseInt(testcase.string)
              });
            }
            return res(out)
          }
        })
      })
    })

    Promise.all(promises).then(outs => {
      outs = outs.filter(o => o) // Filter false values
      return resolve(outs)
    })
  })
}

//empty array
getProjectTestCases([{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 49
}]).then(a => console.log(a)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getProjectTestCases = function (testproject_ids) {
    var out = [];
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        testproject_ids.forEach(testproject_id => {
            out.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                testlink.getProjectTestCases({testprojectid : testproject_id.id}, testcases => {
                    resolve(testcases);
                });
            }))
        });
        //return Promise.all(out) or resolve(out)
        return Promise.all(out).then((out) => {
            var arr = [];
            out.forEach((testcases) => {
                if (!Array.isArray(testcases)) {
                    if (testcases.string) {
                        arr.push({id : parseInt(testcases.string)});
                    }
                } else {
                    for (testcase of testcases) {
                        res.push({id : parseInt(testcase.string)});
                    }
                }
            });
            return arr;
        });
    });
};
getProjectTestCases([
    {id : 1},
    {id : 49}
]).then(a => console.log(a));
```